# gMock upcasting fails on EXPECT_CALL

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I am running into a problem with UpCasting with Gmock

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "gmock/gmock.h"

using namespace testing;
using namespace std;

class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass(int xxx) {}
    int call(int x) {

    };
};

class MockMyClass : public MyClass {
public:
    MockMyClass(int xxx) : MyClass(xxx) {};
    MOCK_METHOD1(call, int(int));
};

TEST(TestMyClass, worksFine) {
    MockMyClass mock(111);

    EXPECT_CALL(mock, call(_))
            .WillOnce(Return(2000)); // times(1) by default;

    mock.call(23);
}

TEST(TestMyClass, doesntWork) {
    MockMyClass mock(111);
    MyClass &myClassNotMock = mock;

    EXPECT_CALL(mock, call(_))
            .WillOnce(Return(2000)); // times(1) by default;

    myClassNotMock.call(23);
}
```

I have tried to use pointers and it looks like it is the same problem. Everytime I have Base object reference (upcasting from mock) and I call a function on it gmock will not pick it up.

I would appreciate some help

Comment: I don't think you've got your example code right. Your `MockMyClass` doesn't derive from `MyClass` and there is no `class` function. It also doesn't have any of the gmock and gtest headers. Please make it compile and fail in the way you state.

Comment: Thanks for answering I have managed to figure out the problem, I have updated the code so others will understand. Additionally I responded with the answer to my question

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I have managed to find out what was the problem. Because MyClass call function isn't virtual I have to use templating technique explained in [Google Mock CookBook mocking non virtual methods](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/CookBook.md#mocking-nonvirtual-methods) or simply introduce an interface for MyClass and mock it normally

Comment: Accept your own answer?